# Is the 'Complete WSUS Installation' process per-user?

Tags: wsus

I've just discovered I've inherited two WSUS servers. The person who looked after them left before I found out.

Some non-prod servers should be patched by these WSUS servers - setting are enforced by a GPO.

Servers that should be patched by them say 'Your device is up to date' with a last checked date of today but they aren't up to date so I started to investigate assuming some patches needed to be made available in the WSUS console.

I've logged in to the servers with an Admin account and can see that someone has done an in-place upgrade from Server 2012 to Server 2019.

When I try to open Windows Server Update Services I get a window 'Complete WSUS Installation' which says:

> The locally hosted WSUS Server requires additional steps in order to complete the installation. WSUS post-installation process can run those steps for you. Would you like to run it now?

There's an empty check-box with 'Store updates locally' and a greyed-out box called 'Content directory path'. I have two options: `Run` and `Close`.

When I click `Close` it says 'You will not be able to connect to the locally hosted WSUS server if you skip this step. Do you really want to close it?'  I haven't clicked `Run`.

The server has a separate drive which looks like this:

```
D:\
 |- WSUS
     |- UpdateServicesPackages (empty)
     |- WsusContent
         |- 0A (a folder)
         |- 0B (a folder)
         |  :
         |- FF (a folder)
         |- anonymousCheckFile.txt.
```

The WSUS folder is over 41 GB in size.

Is the 'Complete WSUS Installation' window for a per-user setting and I'm seeing it because I haven't logged in before?  It doesn't read like it's per-user but it looks like there are already files stored locally on the D drive.  Or is this some artefact of the in-place upgrade from 2012 to 2019?  Or something else?

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The worst case scenario is that you break it and have to rebuild, which isn’t really that difficult or time-consuming for the WSUS role, except for the initial sync-up with Microsoft (which you don’t really need to supervise).

You’re probably right that this is likely a consequence of the in-place upgrade. It can’t hurt to run the post-install and see what happens. There’s going to be diminishing returns on trying to figure out the “why” at some point.

I’d consider rebuilding it regardless to get a clean slate, when time permits.